# Prove existence of $n$ such that $x>(1-\epsilon)^n$ for some $x,\epsilon$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am stuck in an analysis problem where I have to prove this inequality-
$$x>(1-\epsilon)^n$$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ where $x\le1$ and $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ are specified.

Background: I am solving an analysis problem where I'm supposed to show, $\sup S_x=1$ where $S_x=\{x,x^{(1/2)},...,x^{(1/n)},...\}$ when $0<x\leq 1$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I have no idea how to proceed. Please help me.

Comment: can you solve for $n$ by taking the logarithm of both sides?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner unfortunately no. However, basic inequalities using binomial, bernoulli etc are allowed.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{N}$ has no upper bound

Comment: Also you need the condition that $x > 0$ (obviously)

Comment: @SenZen Yes. I have made the edit

Comment: can you use something like $b^n \rightarrow \infty$ for $b > 1$?

Comment: @Phil We have not yet formally learnt limits. So, preferebly no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $0\lt 1-\epsilon \lt 1$

Then $\frac 1{1-\epsilon} \gt 1$

Let $\frac 1{1-\epsilon}=1+a $  where $a\gt 0$

Then $(1+a)^n \gt na $ which implies
$\frac 1{(1+a)^n}=(1-\epsilon)^n \lt \frac 1{na} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$

So whatever $x$ is given in $(0,1)$ , there exist some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$(1-\epsilon)^n \lt x$

Edit : If you don't want to use limits, note that by Archimdean Property of Real numbers, there is $n_o\in \mathbb{N} $ such that

$n_o(xa)\gt 1$ which implies

$(1-\epsilon)^{n_o} \lt \frac 1{n_oa} \lt x$

Comment: Can this be rewritten using Archimedian property instead of limits?

Comment: Yes , I did the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

$\lambda=1-\epsilon$ is certainly between $0$ an $1$. The integral
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\lambda^n d \lambda=\frac{1}{n+1}
$$
Converges, hence the integrand converges to $0$. Your result follows.